# Python's sqlite3 won't fetch all results

Tags: python

I have a problem with my code, I have a database (aoidata.sqlite) and I want to print all rows where "comptype" (column) is one of the elements from my list.

Database:

[image]

Code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('aoidata.sqlite')
c = conn.cursor()
listOfStatements = []
listID = [2, 3, 60]
rangeID = len(listID)
for i in range(rangeID):
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM boardcomponents WHERE comptype=?", (listID[i],))
    x = c.fetchone()
    listOfStatements.append(x)
    if x is not None:
        x = c.fetchone()
        listOfStatements.append(x)     
    else:    
        continue

conn.commit()
conn.close()`
```

Output:

```
(1, 'J4', 35.0, 180.0, 83.9999, 252.0, 0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 4, 2)
(2, 'J3', 463.0, 351.0, 83.9999, 252.0, 2, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 4, 2)
(3, 'J6', 269.0, 480.0, 188.0, 141.0, 2, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 4, 3)
(195, 'T2_1', 1731.42, 711.765, 60.6912, 60.6912, 0, 50.0, 50.0, 10.0, 4, 60)
(196, 'T2_2', 2584.31, 700.237, 59.1059, 59.1059, 0, 50.0, 50.0, 10.0, 4, 60)
```

In my output I only get two rows were `comptype` is 60, but in my database I have 8.  What's wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: You are wrongly using `fetchone` (see @triplee answer) while `fetchall` would be simpler: `listOfStatements = c.fetchall()`.

Comment: @tripleee, the list's elements are only for example, I can have more or less

Comment: Please don't post screen shots of data. This is simple enough to show as just text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` only fetches the second line and then it's done. You want to use a `while` loop to fetch all the lines.

```
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM boardcomponents WHERE comptype=?", (listID[i],))
    x = c.fetchone()
    while x:
        listOfStatements.append(x)
        x = c.fetchone()
```

As noted by @SergeBallesta, you don't have to do that, though; just use `c.fetchall()` to fetch all the results.

Also notice that the SQL could be made a lot more efficient by querying for all the values at once.

```
SELECT * FROM boardcomponents WHERE comptype in (2, 3, 60);
```

You can build this query with something like

```
    values = ', '.join(['?'] * len(listID))
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM boardcomponents WHERE comptype in ({0})".format(values), listID)
```

Comment: You probably meant `len(listID)` when composing `values`.

Comment: @shmee Thanks, too much Awk lately it seems!